# Accessing and changing a class member function from another class

Tags: c++, class, function, variables, member

I have three classes I am trying to link together for my game. I am trying to make it so that if Player1 steps on a specific type of Tile then Player1's gravity variable "AccelY" will change providing the effect of a lift and raising the player up vertically. An initilisation class creates object Player1. (There is only one player so this can be applied to the whole class) This includes header files for CEntity.h and CPlayer.h via CApp.h the main controller class. The CPlayer class is a child class of CEntity. Accel Y is declared publicly in CEntity as a float with no initial value. I want to change it in CPlayer when the player is on that type of tile. I have put an if statement clause in the Tile.h file but i cannot access and update the value using the following code? I initially tried by using the default class constructor but have tried with a function as below.

CTILE.CPP

```
#include "CTile.h"
#include "CPlayer.h"

CTile::CTile(){

    TileID = 0;

    TypeID = TILE_TYPE_NONE;

    if(TypeID == TILE_TYPE_LIFT){   

        CPlayer::LiftTile(0.75f, 10.0f);
        //CPlayer::AccelY = 0.75f;
        //CPlayer.SpeedY = 2.0; 
    }
}
```

CPLAYER.H

```
public:

    CPlayer();

    void LiftTile(float x, float y);
```

CPLAYER.CPP

```
void CPlayer::LiftTile(float x, float y){

    SpeedY = x;
    AccelY = y;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a object of a class to access its members or call its member functions, unless the members or the member functions are declared static in that class.

```
CPlayer::LiftTile(0.75f, 10.0f);
```

can only work if `CPlayer::LiftTile()` is declared as

```
static void CPlayer::LiftTile(float x, float y); in `CPlayer` class
```

Other way is to call `LiftTitle()` by creating an object of `CPlayer` class, you would have to do something like this:

```
CTile::CTile()
{
    TileID = 0;

    TypeID = TILE_TYPE_NONE;

    if(TypeID == TILE_TYPE_LIFT)
    {   
        CPlayer obj;
        obj.LiftTile(0.75f, 10.0f);
        //obj.AccelY = 0.75f;  //works if AccelY is declared as public member
        //obj.SpeedY = 2.0;    //works if SpeedY is declared as public member
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't make the original variable declarations in Entity.h static because they are manipulated in Entity.cpp for a jump function. I have changed the CTile.cpp as above although it doesn't like the rest of the code `code`static void LiftTile(float x, float y);`code` declaration in CPlayer.h or the implementation `code`void CPlayer::LiftTile(float x, float y){
 
 SpeedY = x;
 AccelY = y;
}`code` in the class

Comment: @Mr M: Then you will either have to create a object of `CPlayer` inside `CTile::CTile()` OR you can have `Cplayer` object as member of `CTile` class and then inside `CTile()` constructor you can use that object to call `LiftTile()`

Comment: I believe the issue is not with the CTile class but rather the CPlayer class. "AccelY" is declared as a public float in the default constructor of CEntity.h. CPlayer is a child class of CEntity. Therefore it only recognises AccelY in the default constructor of CPlayer (CPlayer::CPlayer). LiftTile is an additional function only in the CPlayer class. In conclusion the problem is I need to replicate the behaviour of LiftTile within the default constructor of CPlayer but only when it meets the if clause of CTile and not all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `AccelY` with class access specifier as, `CPlayer::AccelY` then the variable needs to be declared as `static`:

```
class CPlayer {
  static float AccelY;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use

```
Player1.LiftTile(0.75f, 10.0f);
```

As that calls the function for your specific player.